# how can i write inside the star shape

Tags: html, css

in the below code i want to write the number inside the shape (star) but it is appear on the side of the shape.how can i achieve this scenario.
thanks in advance

```css
.Stars {
     --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: var(--star-size);
     font-family: Times;
     line-height: 1;
   margin-left:500px;
   background-color: red;
   
}
 .Stars::before {
     content: '★';
     background: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 2.5;--star-size: 60px;
  --star-color: #fff;--star-background: #fc0; text-align: center;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 2.3 out of 5.">3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use clip path property to do that

```css
.Stars{
  
   --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: var(--star-size);
     font-family: Times;
     line-height: 1;
   margin-left:500px;
   background-color: red;
  
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);

}
```

```html
<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 2.5;--star-size: 60px;
  --star-color: #fff;--star-background: #fc0; text-align: center;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 2.3 out of 5.">3
</div>
```

and there is website help you to make shapes : https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

If the background red is put on a pseudo element rather than direct on the div, and with the pseudo elements positioned absolute in relation to the div and given the same width and text-align center, the digit can be made to sit on top of the cut out star.

```css
.Stars {
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: var(--star-size);
  font-family: Times;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-left: 500px;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.Stars::before,
.Stars::after {
  content: '★';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Stars::after {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.Stars::before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 2.5;--star-size: 60px;
  --star-color: #fff;--star-background: #fc0; text-align: center;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 2.3 out of 5.">3
</div>
```